# pp1pHow to merge nested dictionary with a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

My data is something like this
a list of dictionary, each dictionary includes 2 dictionaries nested inside.

```
list = [
    {'adv': {'advNo': '111', 'classify': 'mass', ...,}, 
     'advertiser': {'userNo': '1112','type':'sell', ...}},
    {'adv': {'advNo': '112', 'classify': 'mass', ...,}, 
     'advertiser': {'userNo': '1113','type':'sell', ...}}
]
```

I want it to be something like this

```
list = [{dict1}, {dict2}, {dict3}]
```

merging the last tier and replacing with first tier "dict1".

I've been able merge the tier2 nested dictionaries and created new dictionary with this code

```
dict1 = list[0]
dict11 = dict1[0]
dict12 = dict1[1]
def Merge(dict11, dict12):
    res = {**dict11, **dict12}
    return res
dict13 = Merge(dict11,dict12)
print(dict13)
```

The new dictionary is like this

```
{'advNo': '111', 'classify': 'mass',...,'userNo': '1112','type':'sell'}
```

But since this is new dictionary, they haven't replaced the original list.

What I need to do next is loop the merge (with for() statement?) for all tier 2 dict. so my question is "How do I loop the merge?" and 

"How to replace" them all "dict13" (with loop?) with the tier 1, "dict1".

Thanks!

Comment: `{}` goes around sets and dictionaries. Lists have `[]` around them.

Comment: No, not fixed. I don't understand what your data looks like at all. Please show the starting data and desired results in valid Python syntax.

Comment: oops sorry. I am new to this. I know the data structure but used the wrong brackets.  is this correct now?

Comment: `{dict1 {dict11, dict12}}` is STILL not valid. Dictionaries look like `{"key1": value1, "key2": value2, ...}` Why is it so hard for you to show actual dictionaries?

Comment: Oh i know about that, I've intentionally left out the keys and values for clarity. also my actual dictionaries won't fit in with the character limit.

Comment: But what is `{dict1 {dict11, dict12}}` supposed to be?

Comment: I don't need your actual dictionaries. Just show some dictionaries with 2-3 keys.

Comment: **each dictionary includes 2 dictionaries nested inside.** What are the keys for the nested dictionaries?

Comment: [{'adv': {'advNo': '111', 'classify': 'mass', ...,}, 'advertiser': {'userNo': '1112','type':'sell', ...}},{'adv': {'advNo': '112', 'classify': 'mass', ...,}, 'advertiser': {'userNo': '1113','type':'sell', ...}}]

i hope this makes sense.

Comment: I've added that to the question, now it's your turn. Add the desired result.

Comment: Where do the keys of the top-level dictionary go in the result?

Comment: {dict1 {dict11, dict12}} meant I was merging 'advNo' and 'advertiser' as a new dictionary.

Comment: Don't describe, show it as an actual dictionary.

Comment: i don't quite get it "keys of the top-level dictionary"? Maybe I'm understanding it wrong.

Comment: Will the result still have the `adv` and `advertiser` keys? Or just the nested keys `AdvNo`, `UserNo`, etc.?

Comment: No they don't. The new dictionary is {'advNo':'111','classify':'mass', ..., 'userNo':'1112','type':'sell'} , just nested keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    {'adv': {'advNo': '111', 'classify': 'mass'}, 
     'advertiser': {'userNo': '1112','type':'sell'}},
    {'adv': {'advNo': '112', 'classify': 'mass'}, 
     'advertiser': {'userNo': '1113','type':'sell'}}
] 
result = [d['adv'] | d['advertiser'] for d in data]
```

If you don't want to hard-code the keys of the dictionaries, you can use

```
result = [dict(pair for d1 in d.values() for pair in d1.items()) for d in data]
```

The result of both of these is:

```
[
    {'advNo': '111', 'classify': 'mass', 'userNo': '1112', 'type': 'sell'}, 
    {'advNo': '112', 'classify': 'mass', 'userNo': '1113', 'type': 'sell'}
]
```